# Crazy Librarian's Interesting Prime Permutation Index Number Generator

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, primes, number-theory

You saved the day with your [prime sequence code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/59736/42963), and the math teacher loved it. So much so that a new challenge was posed to the librarian (a/k/a, your boss). Congratulations, you get to code the solution so the librarian can once again impress the math teacher.

Start with the sequence of natural numbers in base-10, \$\mathbb N\$

> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ...

Excluding `0` and `1`, every number in this sequence either is prime, \$\mathbb P\$

> 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 ...

or composite, \$\mathbf C\$

> 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20 ...

Reflecting on how the librarian thought to insert an integer digit into the decimal expansion of a number from \$\mathbb P\$, the math teacher instead created a function \$G(x,y)\$ that takes a number \$x\$ from \$\mathbb N\$ with \$1 \le x \le 9\$ and a number \$y\$ from \$\mathbf C\$ and inserts \$x\$ into the decimal expansion of \$y\$ in every position, in order left-to-right, selecting only unique numbers.

For example, \$G(3,14)\$ is \$314, 134, 143\$. However, \$G(1,14)\$ is only \$114, 141\$, as whether you prepend or insert the \$1\$ into \$14\$, the same number \$114\$ is generated.

The math teacher wondered how many times you'd have to do these permutations before you get a number that's in \$\mathbb P\$, if you took \$x\$ in increasing order. The math teacher called this the **Composite-Prime Index** of a number, and wrote it as \$\text{CPI}(y)\$.

For example, \$4\$ only needs to be done twice: \$14, 41\$, since \$41\$ is prime, so \$\text{CPI}(4)\$ is \$2\$. However, \$8\$ needs to be done 6 times, \$18, 81, 28, 82, 38, 83\$ before reaching \$83\$ as a prime number, so \$\text{CPI}(8)\$ is \$6\$.

Your task is to write code that will output this **Composite-Prime Index**, given an input number.

### Input

- A single integer \$y\$, such that \$y\$ is in \$\mathbf C\$, input via function argument, STDIN, or equivalent.
- For the purposes of calculation, you can assume \$y\$ will fit in usual integer ranges (e.g., assume \$2^{31}-1\$ as an upper bound).
- Behavior for \$y\$ not in *C* is undefined.

### Output

The resultant **Composite-Prime Index**, calculated as described above, output to STDOUT or equivalent, with two exceptions:

- If the *very last* permutation (i.e., appending \$9\$ to \$y\$) is the one that results in a prime, output `-1`. An example, expanded below, is \$y=14\$.
- If there is no permutation (i.e., \$G(x,y)\$ is a subset of \$\mathbf C\$ for all \$1 \le x \le 9\$), output `0`. An example, expanded below, is \$y=20\$.

### Examples

```
 y -> operations             : output
 4 -> 14, 41                 : 2
 6 -> 16, 61                 : 2
 8 -> 18, 81, 28, 82, 38, 83 : 6
 9 -> 19                     : 1
10 -> 110, 101               : 2
12 -> 112, 121, 212, 122, 312, 132, 123, 412, 142, 124, 512, 152, 125, 612, 162, 126, 712, 172, 127 : 19
14 -> 114, 141, 214, 124, 142, 314, 134, 143, 414, 144, 514, 154, 145, 614, 164, 146, 714, 174, 147, 814, 184, 148, 914, 194, 149 : -1
15 -> 115, 151               : 2
16 -> 116, 161, 216, 126, 162, 316, 136, 163 : 8
18 -> 118, 181               : 2
20 -> 120, 210, 201, 220, 202, 320, 230, 203, 420, 240, 204, 520, 250, 205, 620, 260, 206, 720, 270, 207, 820, 280, 208, 920, 290, 209 : 0
```

### Restrictions

- This is code-golf, since you'll need to transcribe this to an index card so the librarian can show the math teacher, and your hand cramps easily.
- Standard loophole restrictions apply. The librarian doesn't tolerate cheaters.

### Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=63191,OVERRIDE_USER=42963;function answersUrl(e){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+(?:[.]\d+)?)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: For 9, `19` is prime, so shouldn't the output be 1?

Comment: Wow, cool answer chart!

Comment: @cascading-style If you mean the Leaderboard, that's primarily [Martin's handiwork](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5139/42963).

Comment: IMO the first exception ("If the very last permutation (i.e., appending 9 to y) is the one that results in a prime, output -1") ruins this challenge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pyth, 35 bytes

```
&sKm}dPdsm{msj`dcz]khlzS9|%hxK1lK_1
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%26sKm%7DdPdsm%7Bmsj%60dcz%5DkhlzS9%7C%25hxK1lK_1&input=16&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=4%0A6%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A12%0A14%0A15%0A16%0A18%0A20&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, <s>166</s> 161 bytes

```
p n=mod(product[1..n-1]^2)n>0
q=p.read
n#c=[h++c:t|i<-[0..length n],(h,t)<-[splitAt i n]]
[y]%i|q y= -1|1<2=0
(y:z)%i|q y=i|1<2=z%(i+1)
f n=((n#)=<<['1'..'9'])%1
```

Usage examples: `f "8"` -> `6`, `f "14"`-> `-1`, `f "20"`-> `0`.

How it works: `p` is the primality test (stolen from @Mauris' [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57704/34531) in a different challenge). `q` a wrapper for `p` to convert types from strings to integer. `n # c` inserts `c` at every position in `n`. `%` takes a list of numbers and an index `i`. When the first element of the list is prime, return `i`, else recure with the tail of the list and `i+1`. Stop when there's a single element left and return `-1` if it's prime and `0` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

### [Minkolang 0.11](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), 85 bytes

```
n1(l*$d`)d9[i3G(0c2c$%$r2c*l*2c3c1+*++2gl:d2G)2gx1c2G3gx]r3XS(2M4&I)N.ikI1-4&1~N.1+N.
```

[Try it here.](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=n1%28l*%24d%60%29d9%5Bi3G(0c2c%24%25%24r2c*l*2c3c1%2B*%2B%2B2gl%3Ad2G)2gx1c2G3gx%5Dr3XS(2M4%26I)N%2EikI1-4%261%7EN.1%2BN.&input=12)

#### Explanation (coming soon)

```
n            Take integer from input (say, n)
1(           Calculate smallest power of 10 greater than n (say, a)
  l*         Multiply by 10
    $d`      Duplicate stack and push n>a
       )     Close while loop (ends when n<=a)
        d    Duplicates a (let's call it b)

9[                                                 For loop that runs 9 times 
  i1+                                              Loop counter + 1 (say, i)
     3G                                            Puts the loop counter in position 3
       (                                           Opens while loop
        0c2c$%                                     Copies n and b and pushes n//b, n%b
              $r                                   Swaps top two elements of stack
                2c*l*                              Copies b and multiplies by 10
                     2c3c*                         Copies b and i and multiplies them
                          ++                       Adds it all together (inserts i)
                            2gl:                   Gets b and divides by 10
                                d2G                Duplicates and puts one copy back
                                   )               Closes while loop (breaks when b=0)
                                    2gx            Gets and dumps b
                                       1c2G        Copies a and puts it in b's place
                                           3gx     Get and dumps i
                                              ]    Close for loop

r       Reverses stack
 3X     Dumps the top three elements (namely, n, a, and b)
   S    Removes duplicates

(                           Opens while loop
 2M                         Pushes 1 if top of stack is prime, 0 otherwise
   4&                       Jump four spaces if prime
     I)N.                   If the loop actually finishes, then all were composite,
                             so output 0 and stop.
         ik                 Pushes loop counter and breaks
           I1-              Pushes length of stack minus 1 (0 if last one was prime)
              4&1~N.        If this is 0, pushes -1, outputs as integer, and stops.
                    1+N.    Adds 1, outputs as integer, and stops.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 324 bytes

```
y=>(p=(n,c)=>n%c!=0?c>=n-1?1:p(n,++c):0,u=a=>a.filter((c,i)=>a.indexOf(c)==i),g=(x,y)=>u(((x,y,z)=>z.map((c,i)=>z.slice(0,i).join("")+x+z.slice(i).join("")).concat(y+x))(x,y,y.split(''))),h=(x,y)=>g(x,y).concat(x==9?[]:h(++x,y)),i=h(1,y).reduce((r,c,i)=>r?r:p(c,2)?i+1:0,0),console.log(p(y,2)||y<2?'':i==h(1,y).length?-1:i))
```

If y not in C, then STDOUT output is empty.

### Explanation

```
y=>(
    //Prime Test function
    p=(n,c)=>n%c!=0?c>=n-1?1:p(n,++c):0,

    //Unique function
    u=a=>a.filter((c,i)=>a.indexOf(c)==i),

    //Generates numbers from a couple x and y
    g=(x,y)=>u(((x,y,z)=>z.map((c,i)=>z.slice(0,i).join("")+x+z.slice(i).join("")).concat(y+x))(x,y,y.split(''))),

    //Generates all possible numbers from y using recusion
    h=(x,y)=>g(x,y).concat(x==9?[]:h(++x,y)),

    //Check if any prime in the generated numbers
    i=h(1,y).reduce((r,c,i)=>r?r:p(c,2)?i+1:0,0),

    console.log(
        //Is Y in C ?
        p(y,2)||y<2?
            ''
            :
            // Check if the answer is not the last one
            i==h(1,y).length?-1:i)
    )
```

Comment: Might be very late on commenting this, but couldn't you save a few bytes by replacing `n%c!=0` with `n%c`; `c>=n-1` with `c>n-2`; and `x==9` with `x-9`?

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 25 bytes

```
D-ṭJœṖ€$jþ9ẎṖ€ḌQẒµL,-yi1$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99F9@HOtV5HJz/cOe1R0xqVrMP7LB/u6oPwHu7oCXy4a9KhrT46upWZhir/jQwe7uh6uGP@4bYg68PtKkAl7v8B)

+6 bytes to allow for:

> If the very last permutation (i.e., appending 9 to y) is the one that results in a prime, output -1

### How it works

```
D-ṭJœṖ€$jþ9ẎṖ€ḌQẒµL,-yi1$ - Main link. Takes n on the left
D                         - Digits of n
 -ṭ                       - Append -1; Call this D
       $                  - To D:
   J                      -   Indices; Yield [1, 2, ..., len(D)]
      €                   -   For each index i:
    œṖ                    -     Partition D at index i
          9               - Generate the range [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
         þ                - Pair up all pairs from the range and the partitions:
        j                 -   Join each partition with the corresponding integer
           Ẏ              - Tighten into a list of lists
            Ṗ€            - Remove the -1 from each
              Ḍ           - Convert back to integers
               Q          - Deduplicate
                Ẓ         - Replace primes with 1 and composites with 0
                 µ        - Call this list of bits B
                  L       - Length of B
                   ,-     - Pair with -1
                        $ - To B:
                      i1  -   Yield the first index of 1, or 0 if not found
                     y    - If the index is equal to the length, replace with -1
```